# custom html/css bootstrap template to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, static

I have a custom bootstrap webpage created with HTML, CSS and jQuery. I am trying to add the site into a wordpress theme. I have read numerous articles on performing the objectives only leading me to a static wordpress page. Below is a link I followed, turning a HTML/CSS page into a wordpress page. The result of the tutorial displays a home page, with a navigation menu that is not static. Does anyone have resources on transferring a bootstrap web page to a dynamic wordpress theme (focusing on a custom dynamic navigation as well as dynamic sub pages). Thank you for your time.

```
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/migrate-existing-website-to-wordpress/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your require my level best suggestion are :

1.For Bootstrap based WordPress custom dynamic navigation you can use [WP Bootstrap Navwalker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker)

2.For dynamic page template please follow 
 a) First of all, try to page templateing at [wp developer guideline](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)
 b)Then follow [tutplus dynamic page guideline for wp](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dynamic-page-templates-in-wordpress-1--cms-28366)

Thank you

Comment: thanks, all worked proficient! But then I reached Dynamic Page Templates in WordPress, Part 2 and received errors. Mostly because that tutorial was complex for me to understand compared to previous tutorial (part 1). And many users trying part 2 reached complications as well. By any chance do you know a good source on adding page template boxes with edit controls? That is all I need for a dynamic site. Thank you once again!

Comment: Great to hear that you have done max part. okay I will try when I will get suitable time ( now out of home). thanks for communicate!

Answer (score 0):

Have an look on this ,

[tutorial to convert boostrao to wordpress site](https://www.charityandbiscuits.com/blog/tutorial-convert-bootstrap-site-template-wordpress/)